# Shutdown MacMini with hardware button

Tags: mac-mini, shutdown

I have a MacMini (Intel Core Solo with OSX 10.6.8) running as an iTunes Server with an external USB Storage without Keybord/Mouse/Monitor. Starting the MacMini is fairly easy, power on the USB storage, then push the power button on the MacMini.

But how can I shutdown the MacMini with this button? Activating sleep is possible, but I want a clean shutdown if I push the hardware button.

Answer (score 3):

For a clean shutdown (the button solution is not clean and there is no way around it, i am afraid) i suggest you to connect to your iTunes Server via ssh from a second machine and shut it down [this way](http://www.macworld.com/article/54317/2006/12/remoteshut.html).

Another option would be through Apple Script. If you have a specific time that you want to shutdown your iTunes Server, or if there is no request inbound to this server for a specific time a script could be auto-activated to archive this.

Though the first option is much easier to accomplish!

Answer (score 3):

I have come up with a solution to this problem.  I run a headless Mac Mini and I always just held down the power button to turn it off until I found out this was a good way to screw up the drive...  What I do now is I bought a Cyberpower UPS battery buck up, and I configured it to shut the mac mini don when it detects there is no power.  I also configured the UPS to then shut it's self down after 1 minute.  Then also configured it to tell the mac mini to restart when the power returns to the UPS.  I have a switch on my wall that shuts down the power to my socket which the UPS is plugged into.  So when I want the mac Mini to shut down I just hit the switch on my wall and presto the mac mini shut down and when I want it to restart i hit the switch again.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is how can you do a shut down using the power button. You could use the methods mentioned by @v2r, but if you just want to use the power button, you have to hold it down for a few seconds for the Mac Mini to power off. I don't recommend doing this frequently, as it does not allow the OS to shut down properly.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Mac Mini M1/M2 Holder Vesa Mount with Switchbot and Servo Power Button Pusher you can print to use for this. https://www.printables.com/model/540401-mac-mini-m1m2-holder-vesa-mount-with-switchbot-and